# Converting DateTime to another format in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting DateTime for OrderDate as DateTime type which is "02/09/2015 4:55 PM" etc I need to convert to the following DateTime.

```
2015-12-23T17:20:00+00:00
```

What exactly is the above datetime and how can I convert it in C#?

Comment: You could (and should) have looked at the hundreds of examples available in the MSDN before posting this question

Comment: Please note that `DateTime` does not have a format.  A format only comes into play when you convert the `DateTime` to a `string` or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following format if you want ISO8601

```
dateTime.ToString("o");
```

Or without sub-seconds

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK");
```